# How to delete emails using UID in imaplib python

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to delete emails by UID. It's a hotmail email account I'm accessing.

Here's what I'm doing:

### 1. Connect to Email

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
imap.login('my_email@hotmail.com', "password")
```

### 2. Get UID from emails

```
resp, _ = imap.select('Inbox')
mbox_response, msgnums = imap.search( None,'FROM', 'email@sender.com')

messages = [] #Appending UID to this dictionary

for num in msgnums[0].split():
    msg_uid = imap.fetch(num, 'UID')
    messages.append({'uid':imap.fetch(num, 'UID')})
```

### 3. Print UIDs

```
print(messages)
```

I get the following output:

```
[{
  'uid': ('OK', [b'1 (UID 111)']), 
  'uid': ('OK', [b'2 (UID 114)'])
}]
```

### 4. How do I delete?

How do I use these UIDs to delete the specific message?

I've tried this without success...

```
for m in messages:
    imap.store(m['uid'],'+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
```

Comment: If you use imap.uid(‘SEARCH’) instead of imap.search(...), you’ll get UID results directly and can use them without refetching the uids.  The command to delete by uids is imap.uid(‘store’, ...).  etc.  All uid commands use imap.uid(...)

Comment: I'm actually doing a bit more than described above so would ideally like to keep it as: imap.search. But just so I can check, can you tell me what the full syntax would be to replace imap.search( None,'FROM', 'email@sender.com')?

Comment: You will find it much easier to use UIDs everywhere.  Switching back and forth between sequence numbers and UIDs is a recipe for pain.  You'd switch it to `imap.uid('SEARCH', 'FROM', 'email@sender.com')`.

Comment: However, your fundamental issue is that you'er not parsing the UID out of your fetch response.  You're storing `('OK', [b'1 (UID 111)'])`, a tuple of a string and a list of a single bytes, rather than just `111`.

Answer (score -1):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX/test') as mailbox:
    # DELETE all flagged messages from current folder (INBOX/test)
    mailbox.delete(mailbox.uids(A(flagged=True)))
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Read lib docs for details